Disabling hitDetectionRenderer in composite styles in OpenLayers
I want to draw a circle around a Point feature in addition to the point itself. However, I don't want the circle to be clickable. Only by clicking the point itself, I want to get the pointer event.
For example in my style function, which is defined for the vector layer:
styleFunction = (feature, res) => {
const featureCoordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
const pointStyle = new Style({
            image: new CircleStyle({
                fill: new Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(200,180,150,0.5)'
                }),
                radius: 10,
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: 'red,
                    width: 3
                }),
            }),
});

const nearSearch300m = new Style({
                    geometry: new Circle(featureCoordinates, 300 / pointresolution),
                    stroke: new Stroke({
                        color: 'blue',
                        width: 2,
                        lineDash: [2, 3]
                    })
                });

return [pointStyle, nearSearch300m]

In reality, my composite style has got the middle point, shadow, text label and four co-centric circles with labels.
In performance point of view, would it be good to be able to use as simple hit detection images as possible and for example leave text labels without detection? In my case, I could just leave the hit detection enabled for the point background shadow style and disable it from the other styles.
I tried to define a custom hitDetectionRenderer = (coordinates, state) => {... to manually draw a 10px radius circle and set that to both styles, but that does not seem to do the trick.
I also tried all possible versions of setting nulls for Style hitDetectionRenderer without success.
How can I achieve the result that the circle is not reacting to click events?

hitDetectionRenderer only overrides styles created with the renderer option.
You could use your source in two layers, styling one with styles you want to be detected and the other with styles you do not want detected, then use a layer filter for your hit detection:


<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html, body, .map {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.2.1/dist/ol.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.2.1/ol.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script>
{

const {Circle: CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style} = ol.style;
const {Feature, Map, View} = ol;
const {OSM, Vector: VectorSource} = ol.source;
const {Point, Circle} = ol.geom;
const {ScaleLine, defaults: {defaults: defaultControls}} = ol.control;
const {Tile: TileLayer, Vector: VectorLayer} = ol.layer;
const {fromLonLat, getPointResolution} = ol.proj;

const center = fromLonLat([18.955, 69.652]);

const source = new VectorSource({
  features: [
    new Feature(new Point(center)),
  ],
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: defaultControls().extend([new ScaleLine()]),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
    new VectorLayer({
      source: source,
      style: [
        new Style({
          image: new CircleStyle({
            fill: new Fill({
              color: 'rgba(200,180,150,0.5)',
            }),
            radius: 10,
            stroke: new Stroke({
              color: 'red',
              width: 3,
            }),
          }),
        }),
      ],
    }),
    new VectorLayer({
      source: source,
      style: [
        new Style({
          geometry: (feature) => {
            const featureCoordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            const pointresolution = getPointResolution(
              map.getView().getProjection(),
              1,
              featureCoordinates,
            );
            return new Circle(featureCoordinates, 300 / pointresolution);
          },
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2,
            lineDash: [2, 3],
          }),
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 14,
  }),
});

map.on('pointermove', (e) => {
  map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(
    e.pixel,
    {layerFilter: (l) => l === map.getLayers().item(1)},
  ) ? 'pointer' : '';
});


}
  </script>
</body>

</html>



or you could use a single layer with styles you do not want detected produced with the renderer option and a void hitDetectionRenderer.  The pixel coordinates passes to to renderer function would need to be used to recreate the geometry which could then be styled using the vector context methods


<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html, body, .map {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.2.1/dist/ol.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.2.1/ol.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script>
{

const {Circle: CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style} = ol.style;
const {Feature, Map, View} = ol;
const {OSM, Vector: VectorSource} = ol.source;
const {Point, Circle} = ol.geom;
const {ScaleLine, defaults: {defaults: defaultControls}} = ol.control;
const {Tile: TileLayer, Vector: VectorLayer} = ol.layer;
const {fromLonLat, getPointResolution} = ol.proj;
const {toContext} = ol.render;

const center = fromLonLat([18.955, 69.652]);

const source = new VectorSource({
  features: [
    new Feature(new Point(center)),
  ],
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: defaultControls().extend([new ScaleLine()]),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
    new VectorLayer({
      source: source,
      style: [
        new Style({
          image: new CircleStyle({
            fill: new Fill({
              color: 'rgba(200,180,150,0.5)',
            }),
            radius: 10,
            stroke: new Stroke({
              color: 'red',
              width: 3,
            }),
          }),
        }),
        new Style({
          geometry: (feature) => {
            const featureCoordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            const pointresolution = getPointResolution(
              map.getView().getProjection(),
              1,
              featureCoordinates,
            );
            return new Circle(featureCoordinates, 300 / pointresolution);
          },
          renderer: (coordinates, state) => {
            const [[x, y], [x1, y1]] = coordinates;
            const dx = x1 - x;
            const dy = y1 - y;
            const radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            const vectorContext = toContext(
              state.context,
              {pixelRatio: state.pixelRatio},
            );
            vectorContext.setStyle(
              new Style({
                stroke: new Stroke({
                  color: 'blue',
                  width: 2,
                  lineDash: [2, 3],
                }),
              }),
            );
            vectorContext.drawGeometry(
              new Circle([x, y], radius),
            );
          },
          hitDetectionRenderer: () => {},
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 14,
  }),
});

map.on('pointermove', (e) => {
  map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(
    e.pixel,
  ) ? 'pointer' : '';
});


}
  </script>
</body>

</html>




Thanks Mike for your answer. I ended up limiting the radius on my select function based on click  pixel coordinates vs point pixel coordinates.
I need to consider renderer refactoring later.
I am still worried about the unnecessary processing of hit detection images. I can see 'createHitDetectionCanvas_' function spending quite a bit of time during vector rendering. Disabling hit detection on layers or features that I know I won't be ever selecting might save some time & energy.
